# Subscribing to a single Eth address doesn't return any logs

Tags: web3js, infura

Using Infura , I'm looking to subscribe to a specific address

At the moment, I don't get any events even though I see them with Ethscan

If I remove the "address" filter, the subscription works.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
 const address = "0x81b7e08f65bdf5648606c89998a9cc8164397647";

  var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe(
    "logs",
    {
      address,
    },
    function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
  );
```

I am testing with metamask faucet on the ropsten network

Answer (score 2):

Dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

Events are emitted by smart contracts, so you would need to listen to a smart contract address to receive any.

Faucets usually are not smart contract, but just an address sending out the funds when is requested by the front end.

This code example retrieves events for the WETH contract (On mainnet).

```js
var logs = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
    topics: []
}, function(error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
})
.on("connected", function(subscriptionId) {
    console.log(subscriptionId);
})
.on("data", function(log) {
    console.log(log);
})
.on("changed", function(log) {});
```

Which looks like this (Just a short sample.)

```
{
  address: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
  topics: [
    '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
    '0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45',
    '0x000000000000000000000000b1a3b3ac90380efa3f06aa06fcb8335925aee3d6'
  ],
  data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012dfb0cb5e88000',
  blockNumber: 15446829,
  transactionHash: '0x9ff570a0701a787282721550f694ac6448ce243ed4049ca40f3363b882ef9ee5',
  transactionIndex: 120,
  blockHash: '0x291891c1c87fe24fdf644f082031f22cd61b511b7dd4744186e1e41fb2139ecc',
  logIndex: 285,
  removed: false,
  id: 'log_b0af76d0'
}
{
  address: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
  topics: [
    '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
    '0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45',
    '0x000000000000000000000000b1a3b3ac90380efa3f06aa06fcb8335925aee3d6'
  ],
  data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012dfb0cb5e88000',
  blockNumber: 15446829,
  transactionHash: '0x9ff570a0701a787282721550f694ac6448ce243ed4049ca40f3363b882ef9ee5',
  transactionIndex: 120,
  blockHash: '0x291891c1c87fe24fdf644f082031f22cd61b511b7dd4744186e1e41fb2139ecc',
  logIndex: 285,
  removed: false,
  id: 'log_b0af76d0'
```

You can find more details and more subscriptions methods on the [Node API reference page](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference#subscribe-logs) on the Chainstack docs!

Comment: Oh, I see. Would my only alternative be to repeatedly ping that wallet address with `web3.eth.filter` to find pending transactions?

Answer (score 0):

That address hasn't emitted any events, it's actually not even a contract so it can't emit events. Events/logs are not the same as transactions. Some transactions will have logs/events, some wont

Events are more-or-less individual log statements that a contract can emit so you can watch them off-chain like you are doing.